# Is it possible to mock a XMLhttpRequest block by CORS Policy?

Tags: angular, cors

I need to handle this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'my http request url' (redirected from 'my web request url')
 from origin 'web origin'
 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

in my local environment. 
It occurs only when i'm not in localhost, and I try to make an api request to my backend after my session is expired.
I do not handle the sessionmanagement system, and i do not need to fix the error
I just need to mock it to handle the error and show the message to the user by a modal but this error is different from a normal HttpErrorResponse, and i cannot get the message properly and I also cannot debug in that environment.

it is not possible to debug

my error handling so far

```
protected handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = "";
    if (error.status == 0) {
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      if (error.status < 100 || error.status > 599) {
        errMsg = error.message;
      } else {
        if (error.error.message != undefined) {
          errMsg = error.error.message;
        } else {
          if (error.status) {
            errMsg = error.status + " - " + error.statusText;
          } else {
            errMsg = "Server Error.";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return throwError(errMsg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need a Interceptor HTTP Error.

Here have a example [Angular authentication using http](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

and to using the modal I recommended to use the CDK overlay [modal pop-up with CDK](https://github.com/jserra91/first-look-cdk/blob/master/app/login-service/login-service.service.ts) and the next step it's put the service in the interceptor constructor... and try!

Comment: I already had an interceptor, i added an extra error handling there to catch this kind of error.. i wanted to mock it because i always have to deploy it in test environment and it takes a lot of time